# android webview and progress bar with relativelayout

Tags: android, webview

I am working on a simple android app that display a website using webview and I am trying to add progress bar at the top of webview. this will work fine if I used LinearLayout but I want to add the progress bar using relativelayout because it works better when I use admobe.

and the problem is when I use relativelayout the progress bar disappear.

here is my code:

```
 <RelativeLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">



 <ProgressBar
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
android:max="100"
android:background="#228b22"
/>

   <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


  </LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Set `android:layout_below="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"` to your `webView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is: Your WebView is occupying whole screen height with its layout_height="fill_parent"

Try placing views like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:background="#228b22"
    />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/progressbar_Horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way, WebView will be placed below the ProgressBar, and your ProgressBar won't be overlapped.

Hope this helps.